# Load data before or after creating activity?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-activity

I know this is a general question, but I don't know where to ask this. I was wondering what is a good design practice: to load data before creating an activity; or to create the activity, load the data and populate the UI.

In my opinion, fetching the data before isn't a good idea since you have to pass the information in a bundle to the next activity. Furthermore, you are handling information that is not relevant to the current activity. The only reason I see to do this is if you have a LOT of data to load and you don't want to stop the user from interacting with the app the time being.

However, I've seen a lot of people who load the information in an AsyncTask before launching the activity, even if it's a few bytes. Why? Is this the expected way to do it?

Comment: Using [content providers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html) and [loaders](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html) might help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't give 1 perfect answer for this question as there is many different ways of doing this.

If you have something that is similar to a news app you'll be able to load content minus images while browsing a list and if the user goes to detail you could load the image on the fly and just display the text. But thats just one way of doing it. Some might prefer loading the image before displaying a detail screen.

My advice will be to think about your users and their work flow and you won't fail completely. And take this question on a case to case basis.